# Use an array to query whether one of the strings exists in window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently search the window.location.href individually:

window.location.href: `http://www.example.com/6CATA/folder/file.html`

```
var searchWinHref = window.location.href;
if(searchWinHref.indexOf("/6CATA/") > -1) {
  alert('6CATA is in the window.location.href');
}
```

Which triggers the alert.

How can I adapt this to query the variable searchWinHref to match one of the strings in an array?

```
var searchWinHref = window.location.href;
var searchWinArray = ['6CATA', '6CATB', '6CATC'];
if(searchWinHref.indexOf(searchWinArray)) {
  alert('alert which code is in the window.location.href');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
var searchWinHref = window.location.href;
var searchWinArray = ['6CATA', '6CATB', '6CATC'];
for(var i = 0; i < searchWinArray.length; i++) {
  if(searchWinHref.indexOf(searchWinArray[i]) != -1) {
     alert(searchWinArray[i]);
     break;  // stop if we found one..
  }
}
```

If you want to get creative, you could take advantage of the [jQuery .each() API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
jQuery.each(searchWinArray, function() {
  //  `this`  now points to the current item in the array  
  if(searchWinHref.indexOf(this) != -1) {
     alert(this);
     return false;   // stop iterating if we found it
  }       
});
```

Comment: Thanks Miky, appreciate the jQuery version too. Been some great answers to my question on here, but I really like the jQuery answer above. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are aiming for newer browser: (IE9+)

```
var isMatch = ['6CATA', '6CATB', '6CATC'].some(function(value) {
    return window.location.href.indexOf( value ) !== -1;
});

if ( isMatch ) {
    // do my alert stuff
}
```

See more about [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

**Support:**

```
"Feature         Chrome   Firefox (Gecko)   Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
 Basic support   (Yes)    (Yes)             9                   (Yes)   (Yes)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var searchWinHref = window.location.href;
  var searchWinArray = ['6CATA', '6CATB', '6CATC'];
  var result = [];
  for(var i=0; i<searchWinArray.length; i++)
  {
     if(searchWinHref.indexOf(searchWinArray[i])) {
        result.push(searchWinArray[i]);
     }
  }
  alert(result.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var href = window.location.href, s = ['6CATA', '6CATB', '6CATC'], i = s.length;

while( --i ) {
    if( href.indexOf( s[i] ) > -1 ) { 
        alert( "found" );
        break;
    }
}
```